# How do I convert a JSON file to a SQL lite database if the JSON file has multiple values?

Tags: python, json, sqlite

I'm new to using Python sqlite and parsing json files.  I'm trying to create a (3 table) database using python sqlite.  I am able to create these tables using the code below, but now I need to populate the tables using a json file. How do I add the json file to the tables when there are multiple values (as seen below)? For example, there are multiple items and I want to create a counter variable (itemid) for each item in the order.

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error


def create_connection(db_file):
    """ create a database connection to the SQLite database
        specified by db_file
    :param db_file: database file
    :return: Connection object or None
    """
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        return conn
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    return conn


def create_table(conn, create_table_sql):
    """ create a table from the create_table_sql statement
    :param conn: Connection object
    :param create_table_sql: a CREATE TABLE statement
    :return:
    """
    try:
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute(create_table_sql)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)


def main():
    database = r"C:\sqlite\db\pythonsqlite.db"

    sql_create_items_table = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items (
                                        orderid integer PRIMARY KEY,
                    itemid integer PRIMARY KEY, 
                                        name text,
                                        price numeric); """

    sql_create_charges_table = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS charges (
                                    FOREIGN KEY (items_orderid) REFERENCES items (orderid),
                                    date datetime,
                                    subtotal numeric,
                                    taxes numeric, 
                                    total numeric);"""

    sql_create_payment_table = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS payment (
                                    FOREIGN KEY (items_orderid) REFERENCES items (orderid),
                                    card_type text,
                                    card_number integer,
                                    zip text, 
                    cardholder text,
                                    method text);"""

    # create a database connection
    conn = create_connection(database)

    # create tables
    if conn is not None:
        # create items table
        create_table(conn, sql_create_items_table)

        # create charges table
        create_table(conn, sql_create_charges_table)

        # create payment table
        create_table(conn, sql_create_payment_table)

    else:
        print("Error! cannot create the database connection.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is an example of the json file entries:

```
{
    "orders": [
        {
            "items": [
                {
                    "name": "coffee",
                    "price": 2.75
                },
                {
                    "name": "espresso",
                    "price": 1.25
                }
            ],
            "charges": {
                "date": "04/01/21 11:10",
                "subtotal": 4.0,
                "taxes": 0.28,
                "total": 4.28
            },
            "payment": {
                "card_type": "visa",
                "last_4_card_number": "6072",
                "zip": "21213",
                "cardholder": "Andrew Luna",
                "method": "credit_card"
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Convert the JSON to python data structures using Python's JSON libraries. Extract the values you want and insert into the database.

Comment: About itemId you can read [SQLite Autoincrement](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)